# How to build design-changing main menu on website?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Please, if somebody know, how to build main menu like on [that](http://apartia.sk) webpage, can you help me?

I really like their menu, namely the fact that when you are scrolling down - it changes . And when you return to top again, its resets to original design. Thanks a lot.

I know how to create menu, edit it, etc. I do not know on what principle works switching of design.

Comment: Use the View Source on the page...

Comment: We are here to help out if there in issue is code. If you want to design or develop the website than you should hire anyone for that work. Hope you understood.

Comment: @ca8msm I know how to create menu, edit it, etc.
I do not know on what principle works switching of design. And i can not find with View Source .
I thought it might be a function in JavaScript , for example, after scrolling action, but it is not .

Comment: @RahulMukati Mukati I do not know on what principle works switching of design. I know how to create menu, edit it, etc.

Comment: It's a JavaScript scroll spy. After X scroll add class(es) to element(s). Learning how to use browser Development Tools (F12) will reveal how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

The basic premise of the navigation you reference in your post is `scrollTop()` ( https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/ ).  The WordPress theme (Avia) used on your reference site has a jQuery function that does the following:

- By default, add a class that applies the transparency effect.
- 'Listen' to the scroll position of the website and, if it is `>50px` remove the transparency class (allowing the default stylings to take effect).  Re-apply the transparency class as needed.

Other than that it's a bit of CSS `transition` effects to make the change a bit smoother.  This particular website relies on jQuery due to it being a WordPress installation, but you can achieve this same effect using any other JavaScript library (or in pure JS if you are so inclined).

Answer (score 0):

Here we go:

You should do it with jQuery script like this:

This will change the page color to blue when you scroll more than 210px, and will revert back to red if you go back up:

```
$(document).ready(function(){       
            var scroll_pos = 0;
            $(document).scroll(function() { 
                scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
                if(scroll_pos > 210) {
                    $("#header_menu").css('background-color', 'blue');
                } else {
                    $("#header_menu").css('background-color', 'red');
                }
            });
        });
```

Or you can see there code source, open the web page and click right click mouse choose 'Explore'(Prozkoumat in czech language). Here you can watch how works it, it's easy:)

Hope it helps;)